# EOS Studio set code permission

Tags: eos-studio

Is it possible to set code permission inside EOS Studio?

I'm getting this error when I try to add one

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, you have to edit the `active` permission of the account you want to set eosio code permissions for and then add a new account to the `Required Auth` section

[image]