# how can my on_notify trigger calls contract actions (permisson issue)

Tags: smart-contract

I need to write a contract that automaticaly mint nfts when tokens are being transferred.

So i have my :

```
[[eosio::on_notify("*::transfer")]] 
void logdeposit(name from,name destination, eosio::asset quantity, std::string memo);
```

This is working fine and i am able to log incoming deposit on a table.

Now my problem is to understand how can i call actions on the behalf of my contract ?

What i am trying to to for testing is simply to return sent tokens.

So after my log deposits, i try to call this action :

```
sendtoken(destinationuser,returnedseed,"Returned leftover seeds.");

 ACTION seeds1::sendtoken(name to,asset quantity,string memo){
    require_auth(get_self());
    print("returning : ",quantity.amount," - ",quantity.symbol);
    action(
      permission_level{get_self(),"active"_n},
       name("testseed1"),
       name("transfer"),
      std::make_tuple(get_self(),to,quantity,"returning seeds")
    ).send();
 }
```

But that throw me a permission error.
So i guess, because the on_notify was trigger by the user transfer it still uses its permission.
That is fine for the log deposit action (which record in a table the current user deposit balance).

So here is my question :

- From my log deposit action, how do I call other contract actions with the contract permission (and its important that those actions should only be able to be accessed by the contract, not public)

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

So i have found my problem, I had to add the eosio.code permission to my active key.

Since im in a local testnet, I follow this post, worked very well :

[Add permission in eos studio](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/6150/eos-studio-set-code-permission/6159)

Now i have a new error :

"eosio: assertion failure with message: datastream attempted to read past the end"

Currently looking into it :)

Hope this will be usefull to others anyway !

Comment: pls mark your answer as correct solution for your initial question.